# displays shared preferences in textview

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I insert the values ​​in sharedpreferences, now I do not know how to display these values ​​in a TextView.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SharedPrefName, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();

        float importo = prefs.getFloat( "Importo", 0 );
        float valore = Float.parseFloat( mImporto.getText().toString() );
        prefsEditor.putFloat( "Importo", importo + valore );
        prefsEditor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing lets try to save something in SharedPreferences, I'm using a method because is easy to understand this way, and it looks cool :P

**TO ADD** in class:

```
private SharedPreferences settings;
private static final String PREFS_NAME = "app_name";

private TextView usernameTextView;
private TextView passwordTextView;


init textviews...

usernameTextView = (TextView)...
passwordTextView= (TextView)...
```

in constructor add this:

```
settings = context.getSharedPreferences(
            PREFS_NAME, 0);
```

***--Save username and password***

```
    public static final String USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String PASSWORD= "password";

    private void savePreferences(String sharedUsername, String sharedPassword) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor SharedEditor = settings.edit();
    SharedEditor.putString(USERNAME,
            sharedUsername);
    SharedEditor.putString(PASSWORD,
            sharedPassword);
    SharedEditor.commit();

}
```

***--Load and display username and password in a textview***

```
    private void loadSharedPreferences() { 
    if (settings != null) {
        String loadUsername= settings.getString(
                USERNAME , null);
        if (loadUsername != null && !loadUsername.isEmpty()) {
            usernameTextView.setText(loadUsername);
        }
        String loadPassword= settings.getString(
                PASSWORD, null);
        if (loadPassword!= null && !loadPassword.isEmpty()) {
            passwordTextView.setText(loadPassword);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you use it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

just find your textview in your layout:

```
  TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
  tv.setText("your value");
```

Comment: ok but now I get 100.982453, instead I get 100.98. How do I set float?

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you want to set the value. If you just want to set the value after saving it in `SharedPreference`, then you can simple do:

```
TextView YourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
YourTextView.setText(String.valueOf(importo + valore) );
```

If you want to set it in some other class, then you can get the value from `SharedPreferencce` and set in in `TextView`. See [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) for how to get the values. Then after you extract the value, you can set it as I showed in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean you need to retrieve these values in a different `Activity`, you retrieve the values with something like

```
SharedPreferences values = getSharedPreferences(SharedPrefName, 0);
float  valore = values .getFloat("Importo", 0);
```

Then get the `String` value and set your `TextView` or just do

```
textView.setText("" + valore);
```

[The docs have a good example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

[SharedPreferences full docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: I did as you say but I get an error:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: this NPE:    textView.setText("" + valore);

Comment: Then that's a different issue. `textView` is not a `TextView` you have initialized properly in your code. That was just an example...use whatever `TextView` you want to display the data

Comment: I used my TextView:                               SharedPreferences values = getSharedPreferences(Banca.SharedPrefName, 0);
  float  valore = values.getFloat("Importo", 0);
  saldobanca.setText("" + valore);

Answer (score 0):

First getValue from Sharedprefrences :

float value = prefs.getFloat( "Importo", 0 );

set float value in your textview:

textview.setText(String.valueOf( value ));